# Java - interface methods naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I've read many questions about interfaces naming conventions, but none about their methods.
Take for example this interface.

```
public interface TableProvider<T> {
   ServiceProxy<T> getServiceProxy();
   JsonParser<T> getJsonParser();
   String getDefinition();
}
```

Considering I do not allow setters, is it worth (and right) to prefix those methods with `get`?
Should I consider adhering to the JavaBean conventions?

Comment: The convention is very well-established in Java that getters begin with `get`. Whether you should or shouldn't adhere to a convention is a matter of opinion. Do you have a reason _not_ to adhere to it?

Comment: @khelwood No, I don't have a specific reason. What I feel when I read them is that the "get" part is redundant.

Comment: It is redundant, but you might have to get used to it. Java is a verbose language, and you will see a lot of getters called `getThing()` because unless there is a reason _not_ to, people normally try and write code that follows the established conventions.

Comment: @khelwood I've written Java for years and I've always had this question in mind. Sometimes I feel sticking to a convention is not the right thing, but it is the better way to ensure everyone "feels at home", I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conventions for naming methods specifically declared in an interface.

Interface methods should follow the same conventions for naming **methods**, which recommend *verbs*/*actions* camel-case method names.

Although `get` may seem redundant in `getDefinition()`, it's still a better method name compared to `definition()`, in light of the "verbs" convention.

One isn't limited to the `get` prefix for all value-returning methods (there are many examples of interfaces with no `getXYZ` methods in the JDK). Where the meaning is appropriate, it's common to see methods like  `createJsonParser`, `fetchDefinition`, etc.

But in my opnion, `TableProvider<T>` and `ServiceProxy<T>` don't seem to lend themselves to a very intuitive, common name for the method `getServiceProxy`. This is why these guidelines are just conventions, something that you or your team can decide not to follow in some cases.

Comment: Although I understand this can be primarily opinion based, it's still  good to discuss about it. Thanks